# How to implement joints in and impulse based engine

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution, physics-engine, joints, hinge-joint

I have been writing a 2D physics engine (for fun and learning) for a while now. I have managed to implement collision detection along with collisions responses with angular impulse and frictional impulse. Right now I want to implement joints so I can use it to build things from ropes to cars. I am having a lot of trouble finding resources on how to do this. I am looking for an impulse based solution as I have been following this https://www.randygaul.net/2013/03/27/game-physics-engine-part-1-impulse-resolution/ which is basically everything on this wikipedia article in a nutshell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response. I have searched around but can only find people talking about fixed joints or some non impulse based solutions. If someone could explain the theory/implementation or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: This looks similar to [How would joints work in an impulse-based physics engine?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125771/39518)

Comment: Oh yeah, it doesn't seem to be answered though.